# Strong Params in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, strong-parameters

I have a model `Peoples::Friend` and my `friend.rb` is :

```
attr_accessible :name, :age
```

I removed this line because of mass assignment vulnerability. I have this controller `peoples_controller.rb`

```
friend = Peoples::Friend.update_attributes(:name => "test", :age => 23)
```

I removed the above line and added the following lines :

```
friend = Peoples::Friend.update_attributes(peoples_friend_params)
```

and added this function :

```
def peoples_friend_params
    params.require(:peoples_friend).permit(:name, :age)
end
```

Now, when I run the API, it says `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: peoples_friend)`

What is wrong?

Comment: What is actually coming through in your params?  Can you copy it out of your log/server output and add it to your question?

Comment: What params do you pass?

Comment: Please post your log. And also `Peoples` is wrong.

Comment: Plural *peoples* may be correct (for example: peoples of Europe), but I don't think it is in this context.

Comment: You might be missing either of the parameters (:name or :age) in params[:peoples_friend]

Comment: No, I am not missing any parameter

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the page from where I was calling this API sent `params` instead of `peoples_friend`. So, I did this :

`params.permit(:name, :age)`